# I need to redirect an email form in PHP Script to another page once the form is sent

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

friends of Stack overflow, what happens is that I have an email form in PHP Script and the idea is that once one sent the message successfully, I redirect you to a page, in my case I want to redirect users to a "Thank you" page.

I have managed that once the message is sent, a green box appears saying "Thank you for sending your message" and when it is not sent, an error box comes out, but I have not managed to redirect once it was successfully sent to a "Thank you" page.

This is the code

```
<?php

require_once('FormProcessor.php');

$form = array(
    'subject' => 'New Form Submission',
    'email_message' => 'You have a new form submission',
    'success_redirect' => '',
    'sendIpAddress' => true,
    'email' => array(
    'from' => '',
    'to' => 'myemail@gmail.com'
    ),
    'fields' => array(
    'name' => array(
    'order' => 1,
    'type' => 'string',
    'label' => 'Name',
    'required' => true,
    'errors' => array(
    'required' => 'Field \'Name\' is required.'
    )
    ),
    'email' => array(
    'order' => 2,
    'type' => 'email',
    'label' => 'Email',
    'required' => true,
    'errors' => array(
    'required' => 'Field \'Email\' is required.'
    )
    ),
    'message' => array(
    'order' => 3,
    'type' => 'string',
    'label' => 'Message',
    'required' => true,
    'errors' => array(
    'required' => 'Field \'Message\' is required.'
    )
    ),
    )
    );

    $processor = new FormProcessor('');
    $processor->process($form);

    ?>
```

this is the html

Name
                        
                      
                      
                        Email
                        
                      
                      
                        Message
                        
                      
                      
                        Submit
                        
                      
                       Thank you! Your message has been sent. 
                       Unable to send your message. Please fix errors then try again.

Answer (score 0):

use this  `header("Location: https://somewahere.com/thankYouPage.php");die();`